# Integration testing omniauth-linkedin and devise, getting a Nil response

Tags: devise, cucumber, omniauth

I'm trying to develop integration tests for devise + omniauth-linkedin, following [these instructions](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing), but the response is nil. The app is working on the development environment, but the tests are not passing.

Test Case:

```
feature 'signup with linkedin' do

  before do 
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:linkedin] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
      :provider => 'linkedin',
      :uid => '12345'
    })
  end

  scenario 'valid' do
    visit "/users/auth/linkedin"
    json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)

    json["uid"].should == '12345'
    json["provider"].should == 'linkedin'
  end

end
```

Error message:

```
Failure/Error: json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anybody help?

If you want to take a look at the code, the project is open source, you can find it here: [StartupDealbook](https://github.com/lucianot/dealbook/commit/a3345de19426542b606045bf76719cf0d54b5d80)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `visit "/auth/linkedin"` and not `visit "/users/auth/linkedin"`?